# Is there an equivalent for "dbutils.secrets.setToken"' in Python?

Tags: databricks

In Scala, with Databricks, it's possible to do `dbutils.secrets.setToken(<value>)`.

Is there a way to do it with Python? When trying to do it, I receive this error:

```
'SecretsHandler' object has no attribute 'setToken'
```

Comment: are you sure that it's possible? what version of DBR? Because I don't see this possibility in the Scala API: `error: value setToken is not a member of com.databricks.dbutils_v1.SecretUtils`

Comment: It's a recommendation from Databricks when trying to get a secret from Databrciks-connect.

Comment: ah, that's dbutils for on-prem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, `dbutils.secrets.setToken` can be used in Python but only when on-prem solutions.